# Load an url with minimal/no DB queries

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, rewrite-rules

What would be an ok way to load a theme template with minimal/no db queries?
Another question: is it viable to 'dry' load a non-wordpress template using rewrite rules?
 So instead of index.php?p=1011 rewrite rule becomes /my_templates/single.php?id=1011 ?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Loading a "non-wordpress template using rewrite rules plugin": How do you want to use a WP plugin to load a non-wordpress page? How can a theme template ve a non-wordpress template? Please, [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/198100/edit) and describe what you are trying to do and the problem you have to do it more accurately.

Comment: That was a second question, slightly related to first. What I thought I was asking is about the usage of a plugin like [Rewrite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/) to change the rewrite rules to my own mustache templates. Not a theme template, I said non-wordpress template.

Answer (score 1):

It is excruciatingly painful to deeply customize WordPress load process.

It's not quite clear if your requirements here are performance related or tied to soemthing else.

For your question as stated there would be about following approaches (madness ascending):

- get rid of actual code causing unwanted queries, altogether or via techniques like caching
- customize the load process in runtime, such as using mu-plugin to control which plugins are loaded
- build a custom SHORTINIT endpoint and load the required minimum of WP core in "manual" way with your own code

Comment: +1 for the Q, and _virtual_ additional +1 for the use of _"excruciatingly"_